# keep webview in landscape

Tags: android, webview, landscape

I make horizontal gallery application then I press any image , I go to website , but when press close to the page , website be vertical and main gallery in website doesn't be horizontal .
notice:application forced landscape in all activities

how can i keep webview in landscape ?
or how can I solve it by any way ?

this is website i work on it and here when i press x to image , problem start http://shoppinz.com/#&gallery=627

```js
package ikh.ago.com.mall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Zara_Women extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView news ;
    @Override

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        news = new WebView (this);
        news.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final Activity activity = this;

        news.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view , int errorCode , String description , String failingURI){
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        news.loadUrl("http://shoppinz.com/#&gallery=627");
        setContentView(news) ;

    }

}
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ikh.ago.com.mall.Zara_Women">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
package ikh.ago.com.mall;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                //answer = "You are connected to network";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ImageView zarawomen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zarawomen) ;
                zarawomen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Zara_Women.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView massemo_women = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttiwomen) ;
                massemo_women.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo_Women.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView mango = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mango) ;
                mango.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mango.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView pbstore = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pbstore) ;
                pbstore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pull_Bear_Women.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });



                ImageView bershka2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bershka2) ;
                bershka2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Breshka.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView gap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gap) ;
                gap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gap.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_men = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttimen) ;
                massemo_men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Massemo_Men.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


                ImageView pb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pb) ;
                pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pull_Bear_Men.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView zaraman = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zaraman) ;
                zaraman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Zara_Men.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView cafehello = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafehello) ;
                cafehello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cafe_Hello.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView costa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.costa) ;
                costa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Costa.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView compume = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compume) ;
                compume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Compume.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView englander = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.englander) ;
                englander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Englander.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });

                ImageView casio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casio) ;
                casio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent n1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Casio.class);
                        startActivity(n1);
                    }
                });


            } else {
                //answer = "No Network Connectivity";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ImageView zarawomen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zarawomen) ;
                zarawomen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_women = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttiwomen) ;
                massemo_women.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView mango = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mango) ;
                mango.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView pbstore = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pbstore) ;
                pbstore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView bershka2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bershka2) ;
                bershka2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView gap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gap) ;
                gap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView massemo_men = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.massimoduttimen) ;
                massemo_men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ImageView pb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pb) ;
                pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView zaraman = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zaraman) ;
                zaraman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView cafehello = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafehello) ;
                cafehello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView costa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.costa) ;
                costa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView compume = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compume) ;
                compume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView englander = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.englander) ;
                englander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                ImageView casio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casio) ;
                casio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
     }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_zarawomen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Zara_Women.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_massemowomen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Massemo_Women.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mango) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mango.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pullwomen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pull_Bear_Women.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_bershka) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Breshka.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gap) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gap.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_massemomen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Massemo_Men.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pullmen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pull_Bear_Men.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_zaramen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Zara_Men.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_hellocafe) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cafe_Hello.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_costa) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Costa.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_compume) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Compume.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_englander) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Englander.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_casio) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Casio.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` on button click to launch the the `WebView` in landscape.

In your `Zara_Women` Class

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    news = new WebView (this);
    news.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final Activity activity = this;

    news.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onReceivedError (WebView view , int errorCode , String description , String failingURI){
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    news.loadUrl("http://shoppinz.com/#&gallery=627");
        setContentView(news) ;

}
```

Comment: Firstly , thank for help me , I test code after your change , the screen is already landscape but webview after press close is vertical . what can i do ?

Comment: please explain where you pressing the close button?

Comment: I want content of webview be horizontal

Comment: in this link http://shoppinz.com/#&gallery=627

close is x in right side , notice main page of this site horizontal already ,but when display on mobile become vertical , can you test it .